# jQuery adding classes to classes

Tags: jquery, class, for-loop

I have a .PHP page where the class `WardDept` appears 20 times.  What I am trying to achieve is to get jQuery to add a further class to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd instance of `WardDept`.  I have the following code:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    $('.WardDept:eq('+i+')').addClass('CorpGov2');
}
```

I assumed that this would add the class `CorpGov2` to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd instance of the class `WardDept` but it doesn't.

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do, if so, any suggestions on where I have gone wrong?

Comment: That should work, other than the fact that it will add it to the 2nd 3rd and 4th instead (javascript indexing is 0 based). Are you waiting till the document is ready to run that code?

Comment: Thanks Kevin B - yes, aware that indexing runs from 0, so the code is correct.  Yep, running this within `$( document ).ready(function() {` - as I said below - it works with the jFiddle j08691 has provided with his code and also my loop - so it must be something else that is going on, checking now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.WardDept:lt(3)').addClass('CorpGov2');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5hNub/)**

Ref: [:lt selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

Comment: Thanks j08691, interesting as your jFiddle example works with both your code and my loop.  So, given that - it must be something about my page/ code that is stopping this from working.  Will investigate further.

Comment: Yep, working as it should do - thanks and appreciated.  Just needed to adjust some code within my jQuery that was overriding this code.